# How to grant access to role in SQL server 2008 only some schema?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have roles created in sql server. How to grant access to only certain schema to roles?

Answer (score 1):

click on Properties of your Role and go to `User Mapping`. There you can grant access for every schema

Comment: what happens if I add schema to securables and don't grant anything?

Comment: I think you can just connect then, but I am not sure

Comment: + 1 no but your advice was useful :) I am checking it though!